# Complex analysis, solving contour integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm terribly but I can't make all those, instead I will post a link with the problem (hope that it's okay). http://www.math.ubc.ca/~sjer/math300/s4.pdf problem 7a at the very top. I've been looking it at for a while, my book is pretty much only giving me a theorem and I dont understand how to solve that one. Thanks in advance and sorry for only providing a link!

Comment: An holomorphic function takes it's extremal value on the boundary. By the way, $|z^2+1|\geq |z|^2-|i|=|z|^2-1$. Then, when $|z|=3$, you get $|z^2+i|\geq 8.$

Comment: That would explain the answer, I can see that they've done something similiar to what you did in an example further back, if you got time, can you please explain why you do like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the so-called *ML inequality*, a standard approach for problems like the one you're struggling with. This inequality enables you to estimate complex contour integrals by the maximum of the integrand's absolute value on the contour multiplied by the length of the contour of your integral. See the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma, where also a good example (similar to your problem!) is given. A good reference on this estimate is also given in Proposition 1.17 in "Functions of One Complex Variable I" by John Conway, page 65.

The maximum (of the absolute value) of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+i}$ on $C := \{|z| = 3\}$ (to keep myself short) can be found by setting $z(t) := 3 e^{it}, t \in [0, 2\pi]$ and then transforming the resulting term via $|w| = |u + iv| = \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$, as you most likely know. The length of the contour $C$ is of course given by $L(C) = 2 \pi \cdot 3 = 6 \pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much for that response, jus curious, you mention w = u + iv (absolute values). What do you put w as in this example?

Comment: You're welcome! I'll try to explain: I chose the symbol $w$ arbitrarily, i could've also taken $z$ or another letter ;-) Basically, you have to evaluate $|w| = |f(z)| = |f(z(t))| = \frac{1}{|z(t)^2 + i|} = \frac{1}{|9 e^{2it} + i|}$ for $t \in [0, 2 \pi]$; Now use the well-known identity $e^{it} = cos(t) + i \cdot sin(t)$ of Euler to get your desired estimate.

Comment: ahh, okay, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Using the ML inequality, you'll get :

$|f(x)|$ $\le  \frac{1}{| |z^2| - |i||}=\frac{1}{| |(3e^{i\theta})|^2 - 1|}=\frac{1}{8}$ where $\theta$ varies between 0 and 2$\pi$, knowing that $z=3e^{i\theta}$ then multiply that with the length of the contour that is 2$\pi$.3 and you'll get your solution.